# c# RESTful Webservice - Error 404 since change of web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-config

I am developing a webservice with .NET using C#. All works fine at all, but since I have changed my web.config file I got an error back from Server reporting 404 - File not found.
The exception occurs after the constructor of the service is done and before the service operation is called. 
If I remove the service section from web.config it will work again. I need to allow higher message sizes because I want to do some file transfers and don't want to split files (mostly between 1 and 150MB as zip) into small chunks lower than 30kb to make it work. So I need to raise the allowed response size.
I don't know why the service crashes but I am sure it is something wrong with my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add
      name="MyDSNName"
      connectionString="MyConnectString"
  />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <!--
      LogLevel DefaultValue: E_ALL, ^E_NOTE, ^E_HINT, ^E_INFO, ^E_TRACE
      Represents: E_ALL, without E_NOTE, E_HINT, E_INFO and E_TRACE

      Avaiable:                  E_ERROR, E_WARNING, E_DEBUG, E_TRACE, 
                                 E_HINT, E_INFO, E_NOTE, E_SYSTEM, E_BOOT, E_ALL

      Development Value:          E_ALL, ^E_HINT, ^E_INFO
      Production Value:           E_SYSTEM, E_ERROR, E_WARNING, E_HINT
    -->
    <add key="loglevel" value="E_ALL"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" optimizeCompilations="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483647" 
          maxQueryStringLength="2097151"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="UpdateServiceCfg" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
           sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" 
          closeTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" 
          transferMode="Streamed">
          <security mode="None"/>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
           maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" 
           maxDepth="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="UpdateServiceBehavior" name="MyApp.UpdateService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="UpdateServiceCfg" contract="MyApp.IUpdateService" />
        <host>
          <timeouts closeTimeout="00:10:00" />
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="false" faultExceptionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="UpdateServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
             multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone give me a hint to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess behaviorConfiguration="web" would be behaviorConfiguration="UpdateServiceBehavior"

Comment: I think you should define endpoint address

Comment: @Adil using UpdateServiceBehavior instead of web will be marked as error

Comment: @husnain_sys the endpoint address the empty address let the address automatically set to basicaddress like it should be in my case. it doesn't work even when I add a specific address there :(

Comment: @my fault, I messed up endpoint with service tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming the webHttpBinding tag to basicHttpBinding makes it work. :)